# Disable all resizing and compression

Tags: images, uploads, compression

How do you successfully disable all image compression and resizing?

I would like Wordpress to use the image exactly as it is uploaded. same pixel dimentions, same quality.

I have gone down the route of adding to **functions.php** multiple strings that change the thresholds and the quality like...

```
add_filter(
    'jpeg_quality',
    function() {
        return 100;
    }
);
```

No joy.

There are multiple threads on this topic across the net, lots of similar suggestions, none of them work/work with the recent Wordpress release.

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was never too far off.

Adding this to your **functions.php** will stop all resizing and compression of images uploaded to the media folder

```
add_filter( 
    'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
add_filter(
    'jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;} );

    update_option( 'medium_size_w', 9000 );
    update_option( 'medium_size_h', 9000 );
    update_option( 'large_size_w',  9000 );
    update_option( 'large_size_h',  9000 );
```

Hope this helps someone

Thanks